# Is it possible to integrate a Facebook page's "recommendations box" into a website?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-page

I am not talking about [this thing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendations/) that shows related pages/links, I'm talking about the box that shows up on Pages:

[image: Facebook recommendations]

I can't find any information about it on Facebook - all that comes up is the "Recommendations Box" linked above. In fact the box recently disappeared and we had to follow some convoluted method to make it appear again (add an address and make sure the map is displayed).

We would like to display the recommendations on the testimonials page on our site. Is there any method to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no social plugin which displays this information, nor is there an API which returns those recommendations